# Automapper: Array to Object mapping

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have one proble for creating mapping from array to object type. so anybody have a answer for this then please help me.

view model (Source class) :

```
public class HealthView : IView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime? HealthCheckDateTime { get; set; }
    public string HealthCheckDateTimeString { get { return HealthCheckDateTime.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); } }
}
```

converted in this (Destination Class):

```
    public class HealthResponse : WebApiResonseBase
{
    public HealthResponse()
    {
        Value = new HealthLine[0];
    }

    public HealthLine[] Value { get; set; }

    public class HealthLine
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime? HealthCheckDateTime { get; set; }
        public string HealthCheckDateTimeString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

mapping :

```
 CreateMap<HealthView[], HealthResponse>()
            .ForMember(x => x.RedirectRequired, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Uri, o => o.Ignore());
```

This is my whole procedure, i try to different way but i got errros.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have solving this problem. but some problem arise my side. so i will give answer later.

Comment: i am trying array to object member mapping using automapper..

Comment: Please specify the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem with this code.

Mapping :

```
 CreateMap<HealthView, HealthResponse.HealthLine>();
```

In Controller :

```
 var response = new HealthResponse
        {
            Value = healthView.Select(Mapper.Map<HealthView, HealthResponse.HealthLine>).ToArray()
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you want to map a HealthView to a HealthLine so try this:

```
CreateMap<HealthView, HealthView>();

var response = new HealthResponse();
var views = an array of HealthView objects from somewhere.

response.Value = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<HealthView>,IEnumerable<HealthLine>>(views);
```